# How to get controls from Grid.Row at runtime?

Tags: wpf

I have a `Grid` with 3 `Rectangle`s in it. I need to get a reference to the rectangle that has `Grid.Row == 3` at runtime.

How can I get access to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var target = myGrid.Children
             .Cast<UIElement>() // make it into IEnumerable<UIElement>
             .OfType<Rectangle>() // and select only Rectangles
             .Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == 3);
```

This will enumerate the children of your grid, and select only those which are of type `Rectangle` and have `Grid.Row` == 3. You can then use `target.Single()` or `target.First()` or any other query evaluation function to get access to the `Rectangle`.

**Update:**

Updated to address Ian's comment below. Very well said, I fully agree (didn't give too much thought to the original example code).

Comment: Your example doesn't compile as it stands, because Panel.Children only implements the old non-generic collection interfaces. You can fix this by putting a ".Cast<UIElement>()" between "Children" and ".Where". You could also simplify the lambda by using the operator that filters by type - you could write: myGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().OfType<Rectangle>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == 3); - I prefer that because "OfType<Rectangle>()" seems to state the intent more clearly.